# \r\n not work in h2 database sql script

Tags: java, h2

Now I am using a sql script to init data in **h2 database.** In the script, I use **\r\n** as a line sperator in column content. But when I get data from **h2 database**, I get the string `\r\n` instead of a new line. What is the **line separator in h2 database**?

Comment: Did you mean it as backslashes ... *\r\n* ?

Comment: yes, I have a column with long text. In mysql, it works. But I can not get multi-line from h2 database.

Comment: Please rectify. The heading of the post shows back slashes; the text in question shows front slashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the function `STRINGDECODE`.

> Converts a encoded string using the Java string literal encoding format. Special characters are \b, \t, \n, \f, \r, \", \, \, \u. This method returns a string.

Quote from http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#stringdecode.